# Access the current session variable from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, controller, httpcontext

I called a method from another controller using this

```
AnotherController oriCon = new AnotherController();
oriCon.ApproveOperation(formCollection, ref responseMsg);
```

Now, inside the ApproveOperation method, I called the session variable like this

```
int activeUser = (int)HttpContext.Session["user"];
```

But its giving me error; null value

I've asked before in forums.asp.net, someone told me to use

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

But I can't use that, there is no Current property in my HttpContext. Did I have no Current property because I'm using MVC 1.0 framework 3.5. Maybe the guy who answered me using MVC 2.0 framework 4.0?

Can anyone give me light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "called a method from another controller"?

I don't think you should be doing that. If its a common function that is used by two different controllers then put it in a separate class and then use it. You should be able to access `Session` from all your controller.

Comment: Hi..

Yes maybe I should just put it in a separated class then use it. But what if I want to return a view from that class? Use that class's view.

Comment: You can use the return RedirectToAction() method provided by MVC to do the same.